# How can I make my code lose the white space at the beginning?

Tags: java, loops, whitespace

main problem: extra whitespace in output

I want my code to print out a step of numbers from my input which I have gotten down. My main problem is the whitespace. I need the out put to be one less whitespace at the beggining.

Removing ' ' from my System.out.print();
changing the loop
Reversing the loop
segmentation

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PatternTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 : ");

        int num = scan.nextInt(); 

        for(int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) { 

        for(int j=2*(num-i); j>=0; j--)

        {

        if (num <= 1)
            System.out.print("");
        else if (num > 1)
            System.out.print(" ");


        }


        for(int j = i; j >= 1; --j) {

        System.out.print(" " + j); 

        }

        System.out.println();

        }

    }

}

}```

I would like the result to be 

Please enter a number 1...9 :  2
  1
 2

Instead of:
Please enter a number 1...9 :  2
   1
  2
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. `j >= 0` should be changed to `j > 0`
2. You should avoid printing an empty space when `j == i`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 :");

    int num = scan.nextInt(); 
    scan.close();

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) { 
        for (int j = 2*(num-i); j > 0; j--)
            if (num > 1)
                System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
            if (j != i)
                System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(j); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I received the following output with `num = 5`:

```
Please enter a number 1...9 :
5
        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in adding an if statement that skips the whitespace at the first time like:

```
for(int j = i; j >= 1; --j) 
{
    if(j == i)
        System.out.print(j);
    else
        System.out.print(" " + j); 
}
```